# Does ASP.NET 5 support Azure SQL as of rc1-final?

Tags: macos, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I built an application on my local environment with SQLite and while I like SQLite, some circumstances require that I use SQL server. I created an Azure SQL database and changed SQLite references to SQLServer references in my project.json, as well as the AddSqlServer() and UseSqlServer() methods but I am getting an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

Does anyone know if Azure SQL is supported? I see that Azure Table storage and SQL Server are. I tried both ADO.NET and ODBC for my connection strings and still stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

According to ASP.NET 5 RC1 announcement, a cross-platform capable SQL client library (System.Data.SqlClient) is now available.
It allows ASP.NET query SQL Servers from Windows, Mac and Linux. As Azure SQL Database and SQL Server are now quite identical, it should work the same way for the majority of SQL Server features.

See the Cross-platform SQL Client section at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-asp-net-5-release-candidate-1.aspx

Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

after some research I've found out that Azure SQL on OSX is not possible as of this moment. I tried it from my windows machine and that worked... bummer!!! I love OSX...

Comment: You never specified `OSX` in your original answer. I'll update the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue on OSx, steps I took are pretty similar to yours except that I installed mssql extension from VS Code, then pushed db migrations.

1. project.json -> I didn't remove sqlite reference, just added "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
2. Startup.cs -> changed to Use SQL Server 
   services.AddDbContext(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
3. appsettings.json -> changed default connection
   "DefaultConnection":"your Azure SQL Db connection string"
4. push db migrations -> dotnet ef database update -c ApplicationDbContext 
   after this normal dotnet restore, dotnet build and dotnet run

Mine is working fine now. I guess mssql extension isn't necessary.